# How to use the linux top command to get cpu usage metrics inside a pod

Tags: linux, kubernetes

I'm currently looking at the solution to get the cpu usage metrics using the linux "**top**" command.
with top command I see that it only gives a momentary cpu stats.
How can I get a **metrics from inside the pod**?
Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you consider using `ps` or `sar`?

Comment: what kind of "metrics" are you after? your pod is a PID namespace, so essentially, all that works outside that namespace works inside, too.

Answer (score 0):

Read docker official documentation: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/runmetrics/

And simple example with one running container on linux system:

Check cgroup version on your system:

```
[root@me ~]# stat /sys/fs/cgroup -f | grep Type:
    ID: 231088ed884bbbd7 Namelen: 255     Type: tmpfs
```

*tmpfs eq cgroup v1*

Search container pid via ps utility:

```
[root@me ~]# ps -e -o pid,ppid,pidns,comm | sort -k3,3 -u -r
    PID    PPID      PIDNS COMMAN
 581250  581246 4026532638 bash
  1       0 4026531836 system
```

Next, search systemd slice for that pid:

```
[root@me ~]# systemd-cgls -l --no-pager | grep -E '|581250'
└─machine.slice 
  ├─libpod-b8f9a94888b51533c7179cd10781b5a72181e965e09075577e60c5b76ccde2bd.scope …
  │ └─581250 /bin/bash
```

After that go to cgroup fs and check what you want:

```
[root@me ~]# ls  /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/machine.slice/libpod-b8f9a94888b51533c7179cd10781b5a72181e965e09075577e60c5b76ccde2bd.scope/
cgroup.clone_children  cpuacct.stat   cpuacct.usage_all     cpuacct.usage_percpu_sys   cpuacct.usage_sys   cpu.cfs_burst_us   cpu.cfs_quota_us  cpu.stat           tasks
cgroup.procs           cpuacct.usage  cpuacct.usage_percpu  cpuacct.usage_percpu_user  cpuacct.usage_user  cpu.cfs_period_us  cpu.shares        notify_on_release
[root@me ~]# cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/machine.slice/libpod-b8f9a94888b51533c7179cd10781b5a72181e965e09075577e60c5b76ccde2bd.scope/cpuacct.stat
user 126
system 18
```